# Is there a way to see shader code run when a game is launched?

Tags: shader, gpu, reverse-engineering

I was reading a bit about shaders lately. Is there a way to get shader code used in games, like you can a program to see it's assembly code?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically this can be done, but in practice it's likely to be very complicated.  How you'd do this depends on how the shader is stored in the program, as well as what API it targets and what version (is it a DirectX shader, OpenGL shader, old school vertex or fragment program, and so on).  Bear in mind that it's been a while since I've worked with shaders, so this information may be a bit out of date.

If you're lucky, the shader is just stored as a string in the binary somewhere.  Hobbyist and tutorial games frequently do this for simplicity.  If that's the case, you can probably extract the shader code with a hex editor or a similar tool.  For a commercial game you're unlikely to find the unmolested shader source string just lying around in the binary for a lot of reasons.

Alternatively, the shaders might be stored in a DLL that's linked in at run time.

In commercial games where there are possibly thousands of different shaders, they're likely to be stored in a resource archive somewhere.  If they're in plain text and you have a tool to read the archives, you're golden.

I believe most shader APIs support storing the compiled shaders instead of having to pass the source to the driver.  In that case, you're much more likely to find the compiled shaders in the resource files.  These would be loaded into memory at run time presumably, where you'd find them in the process's address space somewhere.  If you knew the location you could copy the compiled shader code out with a memory snooping tool.  Good luck finding the address, though.

Once you have the compiled binary, you would need to disassemble it somehow.  I believe DirectX has disassembly built into its API, and OpenGL probably does these days too.

One interesting possibility I turned up with a Google search is [nvemulate](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nvemulate&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://developer.nvidia.com/nvemulate&ei=Mt6_UJyOKIW-8ATjwIGYDA&usg=AFQjCNF8jan0RsmNclwOgsld0mN6Wv782w) which apparently allows you to output shaders by emulating a graphics card.  I have never used it, and it probably only works for a subset of shader features and at abysmally slow speeds for any games made remotely recently.  How it interacts with your graphics card I'm also not sure.